# Нужна ли запятая перед "как" ?

Tags: пунктуация

Я знаю(?) как за вами ухаживать.
Нужна ли здесь запятая?

Answer (score 4):

Это сложноподчинённое предложение, перел союзом *как*, присоединяющем придаточное изъяснительное к главному предложению, ставится запятая.